# Ruby Syntax error when passing block and array to function

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to pass an array and a block to a function but am getting the following errors:

```
./rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
test( [0,1,2,3], {puts 'string'} )
                    ^
./rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
test( [0,1,2,3], {puts 'string'} )
```

Code in question:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
2 
3 def test(arr, &b)
4   b.call
5 end
6 
7 test( [0,1,2,3], {puts 'string'} )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block shouldn't be passed as a parameter to the method 'test'.

The following will work:

```
test([0,1,2,3]) {puts 'string'}
```

Alternatively, you can create a **proc** (which is an object unlike a block) and pass it to the 'test' method.

```
p = Proc.new {puts 'string'}
test([0,1,2,3], &p)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll accept this when I can, it seems counter-intuitive to be able to have a block as a parameter in a function, but then not be able to have it as an argument when you call the function.

Comment: You can also do `test  [0,1,2,3]  do puts 'string' end` if you don't want to use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Methods can accept either unnamed/unassigned block in form `method(args) {unnamed block}` or assigned to proc/lambda/whatever passed as a normal argument in form `method(args, &object)`, where an ampersand symbol means an argument is attempted to convert to `Proc` with `#to_proc` method.

```
test([0,1,2,3], &->{puts 'string'})   # lambda
test([0,1,2,3], &MyClass.new)         # MyClass should implement to_proc

class MyClass
  def to_proc
    puts 'string'
  end
end
```